# aggregation functions with different where condition sentence

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have SQL query  give table of 6 columns from

```
mytable: 
TotalNumberOfRecords
TotalDurationOfCalls
AvgdurationPer
TotalCallednumbers
TotalCallednumbers
Ratiocalledtoallcalls
```

these columns resulted of aggregation functions. but each one have different where condition sentences in order to select from table.

MY Query like this:

```
select ID, 
count(*) as TotalNumberOfRecords,
sum (isnull(cast(duration as int),0)) {where condition1} as TotalDurationOfCalls ,
AVG(isnull(cast(duration as int),0)){where condition2} as AvgdurationPer,
count(distinct  IDS) {where condition3} as TotalCallednumbers ,
count(distinct CGI) {where condition4} as TotalOfLocations,
cast(count(distinct IDS) as float)/cast(count(*)  as float) {where condition5} as Ratiocalledtoallcalls
from Mytable
group by ID
```

Now, my problem is, how can I execute this query in one query to get one table?

Comment: Are you using MySQL, SQL Server 2008, or SQL Server 2012? You have tagged all three. Also, it isn't very clear to me what you are asking.

Comment: Based on the preponderance of evidence, I changed the MySQL tag to sql.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want conditional aggregation.  You do this by making a `case` expression the argument to an aggregation function:

```
select ID, count(*) as TotalNumberOfRecords,
       sum(case when condition1 then cast(duration as int) else 0 end) as TotalDurationOfCalls ,
       avg(case when condition2 then cast(duration as int) else 0 end) as AvgdurationPer,
       count(distinct case when condition3 then IDS end) as TotalCallednumbers,
       count(distinct case when condition4 then CGI end) as TotalOfLocations,
       cast(distinct count(case when condition5 then IDS end) as float)/cast(count(*) as float) as Ratiocalledtoallcalls
from Mytable
group by ID
```

Comment: *avg(case when condition2 then cast(duration as int) else 0 end) as AvgdurationPer* , is this work? i Think it should be *avg(case when condition2 then cast(duration as int) end) as AvgdurationPer*, Both will produce diff result.

Comment: @AbdulRasheed . . . I agree with you in general, but the OP clearly has the `NULL` value replacement before the `AVG()`.